# Can't add a class to a list element and remove this same class from the other elements

Tags: jquery, html, class, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm using a template found online (its name is "[Easy Start](http://freemiumdownload.com/downloads/easy-start-business-free-foundation-template/)") on my website running with Ruby on Rails.

The main difficulty is that i have a layout that contains the navigation bar from "easy start" and its footer, and the pages contents are kept in other files.

The part where i have troubles is here :

```
<div id="divMenuRight" class="pull-right">
  <div class="navbar">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar-highlight btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          NAVIGATION <span class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills ddmenu">
        <li class="dropdown active"> <%=link_to 'Accueil', '/'%></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <%=link_to 'À Propos', '/about'%></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <%=link_to 'Contact', '/contact'%></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are 2 classes at the first `<li>`, called "dropdown" and "active". "Active is what makes the button go red and show which page is active.

So I tried to make a little jQuery function, where I get the current URL and try to add the "active" class to the correct `<li>` while removing it form the others in accordance to which page I'm currently on.

```
var url = $(location).attr('href')

if(url ==="http://localhost:3000/"){
    $("li.dropdown:nth-child(0)").addClass("active");
    $("li.dropdown").not(this).removeClass("active");

}
else if(url ==="http://localhost:3000/about"){
    $("li.dropdown:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");
    $("li.dropdown").not(this).removeClass("active");
}
else if(url ==="http://localhost:3000/contact"){
    $("li.dropdown:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");
    $("li.dropdown").not(this).removeClass("active");
}
```

But it doesn't work, and nothing on the internet gave me a solution...
Am I (kinda) doing this the right way? Or how should i do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are there any errors reported in your browser's console (F12 in most browsers)?

Comment: Concept is valid. Is code inside a `document.ready` handler? Have you tested the conditionals to see if they are matching? Can also access less of url by using `location.pathname` .. paste that into browser console will see it removes protocol and domain from url

Comment: The third check should be `url ==="http://localhost:3000/contact"` And this looks wrong `var url = $(location).attr('href')` if `location` is referring to `window.location`. It should be `var url = location.href`. Now how do you debug your code? Seems easy to check at least what `url` looks like in your code. Anyway, look at Peter's answer below

Comment: `:nth-child` selector index begins at `1` _"The index of each child to match, starting with 1"_ http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: David Thomas  > There an error, but with a library that don't even use and that I'll delete soon, nothing concerning this case

charlietfl > Yes, and thank you, it's simplier !

A. Wolff > Yes, it should be '/contact', i think i failed my copy/paste..i'll edit my question after this comment. Still, when i do console.log((location).attr('href')), i got my current url back, and it was modified when i clicked on my links...

guest271314 > yes, you're right, I thought it was an array at first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer you an alternative means of achieving your desired result, using either DOM or jQuery, but without insight into the errors reported (if any), it's difficult to say why it's not working as written (though it could be as simple as a trailingr slash being present, or not present, in the URL).

It's also worth noting that [Peter de Ridder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34977279/82548), implementing the solution in Ruby is almost likely far easier and somewhat more sensible.

With jQuery, the alternative I'd suggest is:

```
// retrieving the current URL of the page:
var currentURL = document.location.href,

    // selecting the <li> elements with the
    // 'dropdown' and 'active' classes,
    // removing the 'active' class from those elements:
    $('li.dropdown.active').removeClass('active');

    // selecting all <a> elements within the <li>
    // elements of class 'dropdown', and filtering
    // those elements:
    activeLinks = $('li.dropdown a').filter(function () {

        // retaining only those elements
        // whose href property (absolute URL)
        // matches the current page's URL:
        return this.href === currentURL;

    // finding the closest ancestor <li> element
    // with the 'dropdown' class, and adding the
    // 'active' class-name to those elements:
    }).closest('li.dropdown').addClass('active');
```

Using the DOM:

```
// retrieving the URL of the current page:
var currentURL = document.location.href,

// finding all <a> elements within the <li>
// elements with the class of 'dropdown',
// and using Array.from() to convert that
// collection into an Array:
    links = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('li.dropdown a') );

// creating an Array from the collection
// returned by document.querySelectorAll(),
// iterating over that Array with
// Array.prototype.forEach():
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('li.dropdown') ).forEach(function (li) {
    // the first argument (here: 'li') is
    // the array element of the Array over
    // which we're iterating.

    // here we remove the 'active' class
    // from those <li> elements:
    li.classList.remove('active');
});

// here we filter the Array of links:
links.filter(function (a) {

    // retaining only those whose
    // href property contains the
    // (absolute) URL matching the
    // URL of the current page:
    return a.href === currentURL;

// iterating over the Array returned
// Array.prototype.filter(), using
// Array.prototype.forEach():
}).forEach(function (a) {

    // finding the closest ancestor <li>
    // element, with the class of 'dropdown,'
    // to the current <a> element, and
    // adding the 'active' class-name:
    a.closest('li.dropdown').classList.add('active');
});
```

Or, with the DOM but using Arrow functions (ECMAScript 6); the below approach does exactly the same thing but uses Arrow functions to avoid the use of a more-verbose anonymous function:

```
var currentURL = document.location.href,
    links = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('a') );

Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('li.dropdown') ).forEach(function (li) {
    li.classList.remove('active');
});

links.filter( a => a.href === currentURL )
     .forEach( a => a.closest('li.dropdown').classList.add('active'));
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thank you a lot, one day I'll be able to do this with Ruby, but this day is sadly not today, so I'll take your solution and thank you again a lot!

Comment: I updated my answer, you complicate your code by using Javascript for it.

Comment: @Peter, if your comment was intended for me, you'll notice that my advice, in the second paragraph, was to use your answer? Unfortunately, the only advice I can offer, beyond that, is a JavaScript solution since I'm unfamiliar with Ruby as yet. As for your answer I'd strongly recommend, and in this case request, that you comment your code to explain what it's doing, and how it works; that way I, and others like me, might learn better ways and techniques, hopefully beginning to pick up Ruby in the process.

Comment: I know, my comment was meant for Jaeger, because it is unfortunate if he uses a more complicated approach when it is not needed. Usually I add more explanation, but this line of code seemed self explanatory to me.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to achieve your goal through javascript here?

I would simply do something like this:

```
<li class="dropdown <%= "active" if controller.controller_name == "contact" %>">
  <%= link_to 'Contact', '/contact'%>
</li>
```

You can make it prettier by implementing a helper method.

Comment: I didn't know i could do this with ruby, but i still can't make it work, maybe because i'm still kinda new to Ruby on Rails... Do I have to rename "[:controller] or anything?

Comment: You can use controller_name()  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/controller_name/class